# publishing ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, ftp, filezilla

My ASP.NET(MVC) application .. i need to publish it

i tried with **FIlezilla**. What i did was i published the code to my local machine in Folder and uploaded all the files in below URL but gave server application error

http://justpassapp.azurewebsites.net/admin/

This is the FTP [URL](http://waws-prod-blu-005.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net)

I tried FTP publish ..Entered Credentials and i published the site but it says-You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

any help please?

Answer (score 6):

Use the publishing settings in your Visual studio. Use the "Microsoft Web Deploy"-package provided to you by the Web Platform Installer to zip your solution and import the zipped solution by using the IIS on Azure.

Have a look at the following references:

1. Packaging of the project:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Importing of the package
   http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager

You can also define a web deploy in your visual studio