# Production : .Net project upload

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I developed a small .NET project, with the homepage as index.html, which is running fine on localhost.

When I upload it to server, should I start the uploading tree from index.html and the subfolders, or the whole project including `.sln`?

Comment: I have mentioned FileZilla in my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never upload your complete solution (source code) to your web server.

Check out [How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an easy deployment solution integrated into visual studio. This should be enough to fit your needs.

Comment: That's possible too. You can just create a package (publish inside visual studio) and upload it's contents to a webserver. Note, if this is an asp.net project, the webserver should support this. If it's just a plain html/javascript project, it's enough to upload the html files and directories with resources.

Comment: You can also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234015/publishing-asp-net-mvc-website, which seems related.